# Clarification on React components declared as static property within Parent component

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new in React world, and I'm trying to create a dialog box component with some help from react bootstrap modal.

Here's the way I have components built.

Parent (Messages Component)- Messages.tsx

```
           <DialogBox modalOpen={this.state.modalOpen} onCloseModal={() => this.onCloseModal()} title="Retry">
                   <DialogBox.Body>
                       <p>You have selected the messages to be retried. This action will cause the messages to be put back on to the original queues.</p>
                       <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
                   </DialogBox.Body>

                   <DialogBox.Footer>
                       <div className='col-sm-2 button button-action button-primary' onClick={() => this.retryMessages()}>
                           Ok
                       </div>
                       <div className='col-sm-2 button button-action button-cancel' onClick={() =>this.onCloseModal()}>
                           Cancel
                       </div>
                   </DialogBox.Footer>
               </DialogBox>
```

Child Component- DialogBox.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './DialogBox.scss';
import Body from './Body';
import Footer from './Footer';

export interface IDialogInterface {
    onCloseModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired;
    modalOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired;
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired;
}

export default class DialogBox extends Component<IDialogInterface> {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
static Body = Body;
static Footer = Footer;
public render() {
    return <Modal show={this.props.modalOpen} onHide={() => this.props.onCloseModal()}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>{this.props.title}</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>

        <Modal.Body>
            <Body>{}</Body> *what goes in here?*
            <Body>{this.props.children}</Body> * I expected this to get only the stuff that's between `DialogBox.Body` in the Parent but it gets Footer stuff as well.*
        </Modal.Body>

        <Modal.Footer>
            <Footer> {DialogBox.Footer} </Footer>  *what goes in here? *
        </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>;
}
```

}

Body.tsx -

```
export default class Body extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

public render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
}
```

Footer.tsx:

```
export default class Footer extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

public render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}
```

I'm declaring Body and Footer as static properties so I can call them as I did in the Parent directly and it's clear as well.

The main issue I have is not knowing what to include within the `Body` and `Footer` tags. I'd like to pass the contents of `<DialogBox.Body>` and  `<DialogBox.Footer>` from `Messages` Component to `DialogBox` component. `this.props.children` gets everything in between `<DialogBox>` tag. How do I pass the contents of Body and Footer separately to my child component from parent component?
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create your `Footer` and `Body` as stateless components or just fragments, then pass them in as props of a component to render them. Something like this:

**Messages.tsx**

```
const Body = (
  <React.Fragment>
    <p>You have selected the messages to be retried. This action will cause the messages to be put back on to the original queues.</p>
    <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
  </React.Fragment>
)
const Footer = (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div className='col-sm-2 button button-action button-primary' onClick={() => this.retryMessages()}>
      Ok
    </div>
    <div className='col-sm-2 button button-action button-cancel' onClick={() => this.onCloseModal()}>
      Cancel
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
)

<DialogBox
    modalOpen={ this.state.modalOpen }
    onCloseModal={ () => this.onCloseModal() }
    title="Retry"
    body={ <Body /> }
    footer={ <Footer /> }
/>
```

**DialogBox.tsx**

```
export default class DialogBox extends Component<IDialogInterface> {
  render() {
    const { body, footer } = this.props;
    return (
      <Modal show={ this.props.modalOpen } onHide={ () => this.props.onCloseModal() }>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>{ this.props.title }</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>{ body }</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>{ footer }</Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```